# Organic Groups - How do I set a default role for new group members?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have created a custom group role with some custom permissions and I am trying to find a way to allocate this role to group members by default. Ideally I would like every member of every group to be allocated this role, and be able to remove this role from a user if I no longer want the particular user to have my custom permissions.

I believe OG User Roles had this functionality and user roles were put into core organic groups for 7 but I am not sure if this default roles functionality was also implemented?

Comment: OG user roles has this functionality.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7 and User Roles is only for 6, as I said above, the role functionality got added into core Organic Groups but I am unsure of the default role functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this by using og_role_grant within hook_og_membership_insert and hard coding my role in there. This works by granting the role to a user who has just been added as a member of a group.
If I had more time I would create myself a form in the backend so it wouldn't be hard coded but for now this seems to work fine.

```
function MODULENAME_og_membership_insert(OgMembership $og_membership) {

  if('user' == $og_membership->entity_type && is_numeric($og_membership->etid)){
    $roles = og_roles($og_membership->gid);
    foreach($roles as $key => $value){
      if ('ROLE_NAME' == $value) {
        og_role_grant($og_membership->gid, $og_membership->etid, $key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is not provided by default, i'd spen hour understanding that by default users have no role in group where they was added. Maybe i cant find that setting... But seems like for now using hook_og_membership_insert is only solution